# Cancel button on bootstrap modal doesn't clear filled data

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How to clear filled data when user clicks on the cancel button on my jQuery modal form.

Currently when I click on the cancel button it only closes the popup box and when I reopen it previous filled data is still stored.

Please advice

```
 <form id="myform2" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label popup-label">Full Name</label>
                <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name"
                       value="{{ old('full_name') }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label popup-label">Username</label>
                <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                       value="{{ old('username') }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label popup-label">Password</label>
                <input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters"
                       type="password" class="form-control"
                       name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I have used bootstrap validations as well for form fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform2').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            full_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Full Name field is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        max: 15,
                        message: 'The Full Name must be more than 5 and less than 15 characters long'
                    },
```

Edit

Here is my password validation

```
password: {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'The Password field is required.'
        },
        stringLength: {
            min: 5,
            max: 15,
            message: 'The Password must be more than 5 and less than 15 characters long'
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your opening form tag? You can use the `reset()` method with your form name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just assign an `id="reset"` to cancel button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

and following code do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $("input").val("");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/o6mj3nvp/2/)

Or Better approach, use form `id="myform2"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $(':input','#myform2').val("");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example with form id](http://jsfiddle.net/joy0r1Lj/)

OR

With bootstrap validation plugin, no need of above code and any change in cancel button, just add following script above your bootstrap validation script.

```
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        $('#myform2').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
    });

    $('#myform2').bootstrapValidator({
            //Validation code comes here
    });
```

Note: Here I'm assuming that modal id is `#myModal` if not you have to change it to your modal `id`, this will reset the form with cancel button when modal closed and reopen again.

[With Bootstrap validation example](http://jsfiddle.net/js70ooy0/4/)

[With Bootstrap Validation example (auto reset inputs with preload values in form on modal load)](http://jsfiddle.net/js70ooy0/5/)

Comment: thanks.. bootstrap valudation example works for me.. but one more thing now it clears input data when click cancel button, but if  validation errors still showing after reopen popup. please advice

Comment: I'm not getting you, if form reset it clears the value of inputs, so on reopen, blank inputs show and it will give validations error if blank and if not it will process the form, so which part not working as you want it to work?

Comment: what i mean is, when i click cancel button form will close and then when i reopen popup it should work as new form without prevous filled data. its working... issue is ex: if i enter invalid charactors in password and then click cancel , and reopen it, its showing me empty form but password valdiation message still showing

Comment: can you post the invalid character here, i tried in fiddle but unable to reproduce the error so wana check what you are trying

Comment: Also check this fiddle with invalid character and see if the problem exist here http://jsfiddle.net/js70ooy0/1/

Comment: issue doesnt exist on your fiddle. i used bootstrap validation plugin and im getting error messages in different way . i have updated my question with an image pls check @Shehary

Comment: that second fiddle works perfectly thanks . with that excluded: [':disabled'], thanks

Comment: will it also possible to clear auto filled saved data when modal loading ?

Comment: seems like its not working, i checked wuth ur fiddle as well

Comment: sorry, i misunderstanding your question, no i don't think so i never saw any solution which works on all browsers where auto filled saved data can be cleared

Comment: @Shehary, In your fiddles, you didn't include BootstrapValidator js file, you can use files from cdnjs: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.bootstrapvalidator

Comment: And you don't need to use `$(':input','#myform2').val("");` when using BoostrapValidator's `reset` method. The `reset` method will clear all validation + fields values

Comment: @Arkni thanks for pointing out i thought i added as external resourse n i was wondering when OP said error not cleared and i was not able to reproduce the error will update all fiddles

Answer (score 0):

> add new id attribute to cancel button

```
<button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                                                </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // clear input values
        $('#cancel').on('click', function() {
            $('form').find('input').val('');
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: i did , but still same , i have put some bootsrap validations for the form.. does that cause ? please advice .

Comment: Im sorry for that typo error, it should be $('form').find('input').val('');